# How to change package name of Android Project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, package

I have an Android project created in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). I want to modify the package name and application of the project. How do I do that in Eclipse?

Comment: @vamsu's answer is correct, not the one you flagged. Please change it.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

As usual, by pressing **`F2`** on the package name, you can rename or change the package name, and also by right-clicking and then select `Rename` option, you can change or rename the package name.

When you press <kbd>F2</kbd>, it will show you the dialog box as:

[image]

In this dialog, don't forget to check the "Update references" checkbox because by making "check" to this check-box, it will make changes to all the references of the package which are referred by other components of project.

Comment: right click > Rename  does not seems to be an option in Eclipse Helios.But `F2` on package name works.

Comment: Just don't forget the XML file, because you have to update it manually.

Comment: u dont have to update the XML manulay..go to search >file >com.yourpackage >replace > new Package name

Comment: Look for `Rename` command under `Refactor` if that is not at the root of the context menu.

Comment: Hey, this is actually an android project so it won't compile like this! You must use Android Tools to rename package, as @vamsu says.

Comment: I had to rename package name in AndroidManifest.xml manually. "Rename application package" in "Android tools" did not work.

Comment: "Note: This doesn't seem to work in Eclipse 3.8, because the option to check "update references" wasn't there. Instead, I manually renamed the package name at the head of the classes, and in the xml files."

Answer (score 141):

This is [a bug in the Eclipse Android tools](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2824).

To fix: Right click on the project, go to Android tools -> Rename application package.

And also check `AndroidManifest.xml` if it updated correctly. In my case it didn't, and that should solve this problem.

Comment: This worked for me in the following way. It changed all files in gen folder and in AndroidManifest.xml.

Then I went back to my package (in src folder) which hadn't changed. I redid Right Click -> Refactor -> Rename. Entered the new name and bingo. Done

Comment: Thanks! This way OK. The accept one make my App crash

Answer (score 10):

None of these worked for me, they all introduced errors.

The following worked for me:

- Right click the project and select Android Tools >> Rename
  Application Package.
- Enter the new Package name
- Accept all the automatic changes it wants to make
- Say yes to update the launch configuration

Comment: Wowww!! that's a perfect one.

Answer (score 9):

One *extremely important* notice:

**NEVER** use a direct package names as in something similar to passing a string value containing the package name. Use the method getPackageName(). This will make the renaming dynamic. Do whatever to reach the method getPackageName().

In Eclipse Juno, the correct way of renaming is:

1. Go and edit the manifest.
2. Remove every old package name in the manifest.
3. Put instead of the old package name, the new package name in every location inside the manifest. You might have classes (Activities that is) that need direct package name references.
4. Save the manifest.
5. Then right click the package name inside the project.
6. Select "Refactor".
7. Select "Rename".
8. Type the new package name.
9. Select "update references".
10. Press OK and you're done and watch out also what should be done to replace the new name.
11. *Don't* forget to also update the layout XML files with the new package name. You might have a custom View. Look for them.

Answer (score 7):

```
 Right click on your project name and select Android Tools , then click 
 Rename Application Package, then change your project name click OK and 
 click Finish.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just right click on the project name and select *Android tools* and click *Rename Application Package name* and rename it. It's only for Android projects.

Answer (score 4):

To change the app name when in Android, go to `res/values/strings.xml` and change `app_name` to what you want.

Comment: Package name is different to application name!

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then rename it (or right click on the project and select `Rename`). It changes wherever that package is declared in your project. It's automatically renamed all over.

Answer (score 2):

Goto the *Src* folder of your Android project, and open the Java file.

Change the package `OldName.android.widget` to `newName.android.widget`.

It gives you an error like this

> The declared package "newName.android.widget" does not match the expected package "OLDName.android.widget.

To fix this problem, select *Move filename.Java to Newname.android.widget* and delete the old package folder.

Next step: Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and change 
`package="OldName.android.widget"` to `package="newName.android.widget"`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me (simple text replace):

Go to search -> file

Containing text: old pakage name

File name pattern: *

Scope: workspace

Press *Replace*

Replace: new package name

Now your project is full of errors.

Click your package in project explorer and press <kbd>F2</kbd> (rename).

Fill in the new package name and check all checkmarks.

Press *Preview*.

Click *OK*.

Wait for Eclipse to refresh. If there are still errors, clean all projects in the workspace:

*Project* -> *Clean*

Answer (score 2):

None of this worked for me until I combined the two answers mentioned in this post.

Step 1: Right click on the project -> Select Android Tools -> Rename application Package.
(This will change all the files in the gen folder and in AndroidManifest but will not change the package name in the src folder so I followed Step 2)

Step 2: Inside src folder Right Click your package name -> Refactor -> Rename -> Enter the new name that you entered in Step 1.

Just to make sure Check AndroidManifest if there is still the old package name and replace with the new one (in my case inside the "uses-permission" tag).

Then close the Eclipse and Reopen it. Uninstall the app from your device and install it again and everything should be working fine.

Hope this helps and saves your time.

Answer (score 1):

OK here's what I had to do:

Problem: 
I had a base project that I wanted to use as a starting point for several other projects that would be in the same workspace as the base project.  The base project was already under GiT control in my own local repo.  It was time to duplicate the base project, "MyBaseApp", to become the starting point for "MyKillerApp."

Solution:

1. I just duplicated the overall MyBaseApp directory as MyKillerApp and had the two directories side-by-side.
2. I edited file MyKillerApp->.project and changed the name from MyBaseApp to MyKillerApp.  (This was necessary for step 3 to work.)
3. I opened Eclipse and did a File->Import of MyKillerApp (I left out some details about how to use the Import menu, but click around, you'll figure it out.)
4. I right clicked on MyKillerApp in the package manager and chose Android Tools->Rename Application Package to MyKillerApp.  I checked all the options for renaming except the last checkbox about non-java files.
5. I highlighted src->com.myname.MyBaseApp in the package manager and did an F2 to MyKillerApp.  Then I did the same to a few classes including my opening activity class thing that goes into your AndroidManifest.xml file.
6. I had to update a few function call names but the compiler pointed them out to me handily.

Thus I had a new project derived from a base project with no nomenclature left over from the base project and it was in its own local GiT repo.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me in eclipse:

Go to AndroidManifest, search and replace old package name with new one and update everything when saving. Go to your root project package then press F2, write new name, and check Update References and Rename subpackages check boxes. After this everything was red in project (complaining about R import for every java file) because it wasn't changing closing tag of my custom view-s in layout xmls. After I changed these manually, everything was back to normal. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Just get [Far Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Manager) and search through for the old name. Then manually (in Far Manager) replace everywhere. Sadly, this is the only method that works in 100% of the possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had big trouble with this too.

I renamed the project and the package via refactoring, but it rendered the app useless. I renamed it back to the original and used the Android tools to rename the package and this worked, but my package folder and classes had the old name.

I then refactored the package folder. Now the app wouldn't run. My manifest was a mess. It doubled up my launcher name for example, `com.ronguilmet.app/com.ronguilmet.com.class`. I fixed that, and I had to manually edit all activities.

Answer (score 0):

**Renaming an Application- The Complete Guide**

```
**A) for changing Just the application name
   (App name which is displayed below icon)
    in the Manifest.xml file, in <application tag, 
    android:label="YourAppName"
    then do the same in All the <activity Tags        

  B) For changing EVERYTHING 
   (folder names, Package names, Refrences,app name, etc.)
  *1) Renaming package names in gen folder and manifest.xml
      Right Click on Your project
      Android tools- Rename Application Package

  *2) Renaming package names in src folder 
      Expand src folder, Click on package (Single click) 
      Press Alt+Shift+R
      Check Update references and Rename subpackages      
   3) Renaming the app's main Folder (Optional)
      click on the application's folder (Single click)
      then Press Alt+Shift+R 

   4) Renaming application name- Refer "A)"**
```