# What are proper steps to rename an application in Android?

Tags: android, refactoring, rename

I usually code games that the boss hasn't decided its name yet, and he usually gives the name once it is finished. However, when I rename all old name to new name, many issue happens.

For example: when starting a project, I set `application name` to `abc`, `package name` to `com.company.abc`, then the given game name is `def`, how can I change all the related to new name, without forget anywhere?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: use refactor->rename to reflect changes to new name

Comment: They just rename the package, not the application name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do in such a situation is rename the `package` that will automatically change the `references` and for changing the app name you should change

```
res> values> strings> app_name
```

to the name what you want

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `app_name` is an "official" name of the application. I thought it is simply a string using for coder. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Application has two components:
1. Packages 
2. Application

To change the package name:
Right click on the application, click on android tools in the list, click on rename application package option. This should change your application package name .

To change the application name:
App name can be changed by changing the app_name in the strings of your resource folder.