# duplicate an android app project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is it possible to duplicate my android app and just give it a new namespace? 
Creating a copy of this app for another event and instead of going through and copy/paste all files, I was hoping to be able to duplicate the project and choose a new namespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Package renaming in eclipse android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: @Niek that question seems to be about renaming a project rather than creating a copy of it with a new name as the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a copy of the Project, select the package name in the 'src/' folder, press F2 , set the new name and update all references automatically.
It probably won't update all references correctly though, but it will update most of them.

Comment: This worked. Don't forget to rename it in the AndroidManifest.xml file as well. Also i had to clean the project, rebuild and restart eclipse. Then it worked.