# How to specify the package name of R.java to be different from app package name

Tags: android, adt, r.java-file

We have our application with declared package name as **com.foo.app** in AndroidManifest.xml

For some special reason to play some trick, we want to intentionally specify the package name of the generated R.java with package name **com.bar.resource**. And without change the application package name (still kept as com.foo.app).

For example, I have my application using com.foo.app, I want the generated R.java's package name to be com.bar.resource. And in the source code of my application, I will use reference like `com.bar.resource.id.btn_ok`

We know that we should not touch the content of R.java. And of course we can manually change it and build the final application since it is just a static class with constants.

But is there any configurable option in ADT/Eclipse to do this for an Android project?

---

*Please stop telling me how to change the package name via Eclipse refactor method*. Please correctly understand my question. I am asking how to specify a package name of **autogenerated R.java**. Which I want it to be ***different*** from the application package name specified in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Check: [Package renaming in eclipse android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: Thanks for your information, but I want a different package name for R.java

Comment: what do you mean by different package name for R.java?

Comment: For example, I have my application using com.foo.app, I want the generated R.java's package name to be com.bar.resource. And in the source code of my application, I will use reference like com.bar.resource.id.btn_ok

Comment: As far as I know you can't rename or change R.java and its contents. (If you try to change contents, it will warn you and its not advisable)

Comment: Yes I know, that is why I am here.

Answer (score 2):

I've run the exact same issue myself recently and found the best solution to actually have a smaller sub-project that I reference with the package name I want.

I use ADT, so I have

|Parent project|

-> |Sub project|

I use ADT and sub project is marked as a Library project, and referenced to (both in Android, Java Build Path, and Project Dependencies) so then parent project gets references to all of the resources in there, so I can give it whatever package name I want.

I've thrown a quick and dirty example of this setup on https://github.com/SixMinute/AndroidSeparatePackageResources.

It's not an absolutely perfect setup, but it definitely works the best and easiest for us, hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

R.java package name is depend on package name that you define in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Open src folder in the package explorer and then right click on com.foo.resource,then click on refactor then rename the package name and all relevant entries will also be renamed.

Comment: Hi, you misunderstood my question. I am asking for change the auto generated source code of R.java. Not a manually created resource package.

Comment: try renaming the gen folder and deleting the previous one

Comment: Thanks, but that is too trivial since every time eclipse will generate a new one. And I don't want to modify R.java code, just change its package name.

Comment: You can stop automatic generation of new R file by un-checking build automatically option in Project menu

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps to change package name if you are using Eclipse,

1. Right-click on the package name.
2. Select Refactor > Rename
3. Open the manifest file. Inside the  tag, change the package name..
4. import the package in the relevant classes as it is changed.