# Is there an easy way to have a test version of an app and a release version installed on an android phone?

Tags: android, versioning

Say I have a production version com.android.xyz and this is production
then I am developing something and i want to load both this version and the production version on my phone so it's side by side. I know I can create a new package like com.android.abc and then I would have a second app which is basically a clone of com.android.xyz.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Reid

Comment: AFAIK, changing the package name is the only way to do this.

Comment: ahh yeah i know the package name is basically the way to do this, so I would simply change the package name, and run a script to go into each file and project and change everything to reference the new package name using some kind of script.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the **Android** package name with the **Java** package structure. You can change the former without changing the later.

Comment: yeah so when I change the android package name, then the whole code doesn't compile.  I'll try this again on Monday though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*IF* you are using Android Studio with Gradle, there is an easy way to do this.  I still keep the the same packageName in AndroidManifest.xml (at least current gradle needs this duplicate definition)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
package="com.android.xyz">
```

build.gradle

```
def devBuildName = "dev"
def testBuildName = "test"

android {
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 70
    versionName "2.2.3"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    packageName "com.android.xyz"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        packageNameSuffix "."+devBuildName
        versionNameSuffix "-"+devBuildName.toUpperCase()
    }

    test.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    test {
        packageNameSuffix "."+testBuildName
        versionNameSuffix "-"+testBuildName.toUpperCase()
    }
}
}
```

You can look at my full dev/release example at [github](https://github.com/fsiu/dw2020).

Comment: This just requires Gradle. Android Studio uses Gradle, but you do not need Android Studio to use Gradle.

Comment: yes i think i'm gonna have to give gradle a try!  Thanks everyone!

Comment: The other way is to do it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project

manually , but its just a 2 button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the package name.  IMO the easiest way to do this is by writing a perl/python script to iterate through the files and change the package name based on the build type.  Or run a C style macro preprocessor over the files first.