# "Unfortunately your App has stopped working"

Tags: android

I was going to upload my apk in google developers console, but I got an error message "change package name an upload again".

So I followed the following step:

1: Goto android manifest file--> Change package name to "com.example"

2: So many errors were there in src folder.

3: So going to src folder I changed the name of that particular folder("com.example1") to some ("com.example2")
    then all errors are gone!

4: But while launching the apk in the phone, I am getting something like this all the time-->

"Unfortunately "app name" has stopped"

Can you please help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look in logcat. (the debug window) where all the logs are showed. 
If you use IntelliJ (recommended) checkout this article https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/android-tool-window.html to help you started with the debugging.