# Want to publish app with same pakagename by different Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-package-managers

I have an app in Google Play Store. But unfortunately I am unable to upload new app by same Google Play store.

So I want to publish app with another Google ID with same pakagename.

Example:

Existing App Pakage Name: pakage.abir.xxx.xx
Existing Google Play Store ID: abir.xxx.xx

Proposed App Pakage Name: pakage.abir.xxx.xx
Proposed Google Play Store ID: mustafiz.xxx.xx

Please suggest me is it possible to upload same pakagename app by different Google ID?

Thanks
Mustafiz

Comment: you can transfer the ownership to new account!  look here > 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/how-to-change-package-name-of-android-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to transfer the application to a different account. You can request to transfer the app to a different account from Google here:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appt

Comment: Have need to purchase new Google Play store account transfer the application?

Comment: You just have to pay Google $25 for the developer fee for new account and you can get refund for developer fee from other account.