# Upload of APK to Google Play fails because of different package names

Tags: java, android, package

I have a problem uploading my APK to the Google Play store because of different package names.
What I've done is the following:

- I uploaded the APK without any problems.
- The app is not published yet; the state is announced with "design".
- Now I renamed the Java packages.
- I changed the "package" attribute in AndroidManifest.xml to the new name.
- I changed the android:versionCode from 1 to 2.
- Then I built the APK and tried to upload to Google Dev Console but it fails with the message that the package names are different.

Is there a way to solve this conflict? I know I could "reset" my Java project to the old name but I want to keep the new package name and publish this one to Google Play for all future versions.

Comment: You need to keep the same package name, if you change it you need to make a whole new app listing

Answer (score 0):

You should also change the application id in your app.gradle :
android {

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "type the new app Id here "

}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say: I'm using eclipse for Android Developers. There's no gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new APK with the updated names and then put the new APK in Google Play?

Comment: This is exactly my problem: I created a new APK with the new names but can't upload it.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Hope it gets solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't publish the app, just go ahead and create a new application under the new package.

Comment: Is this possible with the same application name? Do you mean a new store entry? Can I delete the current one?

Comment: The name is just a string. The only thing that truly matters is the application package also know as the application id. I don't know if you can delete the old application 100% even if you haven't published yet. But you can have more than one store listings, even for the same binary if the application id is different.

Comment: Now I created a new store entry with the same title/app name and filled out all necessary fields. Then I clicked under "app versions". Here I get the message that I already have one unpublished version and I only have the possibility to click "edit version". I've no idea how to upload my new APK for my new store entry.

Comment: Did you create it with a new release key and new package? Add some screenshots, is really hard to guess

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to check the "Update references" checkbox when you rename your project.

Check this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698165/8239508